# Want to study Graduate Measure Theory with heavy Emphasis on Topology and/or Geometry.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, differential-geometry, book-recommendation, geometric-measure-theory

I did one course in Measure Theory and want to study it again. But this time I want to do this in a way that emphasizes Measure Theoretic structure on Geometric or Topological Spaces. I don't know, if it is at all possible. But I have heard there are some Differential forms and Measure theoretic relations on manifolds. So, my question is,-

1. Do you know a graduate level literature (book,notes,lectures anything) on Measure Theory that you think is topologically or Geometrically heavy (in your judgement) ? Showing an interplay between Measure theory and topology/geometry is desired but any other reasons that you have is good too.
2. More specifically, Is there anything for measure theory on manifolds?
3. Is reading Geometric Measure Theory a good idea for this?

I asked this on Reddit too. But I need more opinions.Thank You.

Comment: I've heard many things about Federer's book on Geometric Measure Theory – not all of them good... It might be of interest to you, though.

Comment: I'm not sure GMT is what you are looking for (unless you are interested in things like minimal submanifolds).  Maybe you are looking for smooth ergodic theory or something of that nature?  See, e.g., [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-148) or [this PDF](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/irene.pasquinelli/dyn/SLII.pdf).

Comment: Maybe ["Geometric Measure Theory"](https://www.elsevier.com/books/geometric-measure-theory/morgan/978-0-12-804489-6) by F. Morgan.

Comment: When you say "emphasizes Measure Theoretic approach over Geometric or Topological Spaces" I take it you mean something like "measure theory on geometric spaces" rather than "measure theory instead of geometric/topological spaces"?

Comment: @T_M   yes, I mean Measure Theory on Geometric Spaces.

Comment: Q.2 I can roughly answer as "no", that isn't really a subject itself. But generally I don't really know how to answer. My main thought it just: Why? Why do you want to study measure theory 'again'? Why do you need it to be somehow blended with geometry and topology? What do you really want to know about? What context are you learning in? What is the 'cost' of learning? i.e. why don't you just get some books/notes and have a look?

Comment: If you have only a first course in measure theory, I assume that you have only basic $L^p$ theory and some convergence theorems. You might consider reading a bit more on measure theory (say Hausdorff measure) before moving on.

Comment: For question 2, the borel sigma algebra might be of use.

Comment: @T_M I am interested in Geometry/Topology in General. 1) I want to study Measure Theory again because I am feeling like it. 2) I want to know about Compatible Measure Theoretic structures on geometric and topological Spaces purely out of curiosity. 3) The thing I want to know about is nothing too specific and it is told in the 2nd answer. 4) Curiosity is the context as stated in 2nd answer. 5) To get recommendations on notes and/or books is the reason I asked the question. Thank You.

Comment: @Arctic Char I have done Terry Tao's book on Measure Theory(not too thoroughly). I found out 4th volume of  Fremlin has Topological Measure Space. I am thinking to start reading it slowly.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thank You. It feels like a good intro book about minimal surfaces after skimming.

Comment: @user10354138   Thank You for finding out smooth ergodic theory. I didn't know it existed. I will check it out.